# uuid in url, is it friendly to google?

Tags: url, seo, uuid

My database uses uuid as primary keys, and the urls are like:

`http://aaa.com/questions/a2f1c81a-b9a9-4a1d-804d-5324a8705976`

Is it friendly to search engines like google? I can use autoincreased long integer as primary keys too, is it better?

The url will be:

`http://aaa.com/questions/1234212`

Comment: @all, I think this is a program question, because if it is friendly to google, I will use uuid, otherwise I will use sequence.

Comment: I agree, it's programming related

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible to answer with certainty as Google keeps it ranking algorithm secret (and updates them frequently), but I doubt it would matter either way.

However, generally speaking, if you want to improve search engine rankings, include keywords in your URLs (the way StackOverflow does).  Your web application can just use your unique identifier and ignore these additional URL elements.

Comment: it seems few people use UUID in url, and I found StackOverflow uses global seq(questions,answers,comments share a same sequence), so I decide to use sequence now. Thank you

Comment: Jen is correct, although in the same vein a lot of websites rank well with poor URL's. In all honesty I think it doesn't really matter, as links to your site are far more important than what you do with your own.